# How to use twitter bootstrap icon with google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, twitter-bootstrap

```
<i class="icon-search"></i>
```

Tried to put the above line in google app engine.  Apparently, it doesn't work because I haven't link the image file to the app.yaml file. The app.yaml file already has the following code:

```
- url: /static/images/(.*\.(gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
  static_files: static/images/\1
  upload: static/images/(.*\.(gif|ico|jpeg|jpg|png))
```

What should I do to use Twitter Bootstrap icons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have to do is to point correctly where are the two sprite images that are coming with Bootstrap.

If you are using LESS then find these lines in the `variables.less`:

```
@iconSpritePath:          "../img/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

and change them to something like this:

```
@iconSpritePath:          "/static/images/glyphicons-halflings.png";
@iconWhiteSpritePath:     "/static/images/glyphicons-halflings-white.png";
```

If these images are located in the `static/images` directory.

Otherwise if you are using the CSS version of Bootstrap then just locate the references to these images and put the correct path:

```
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png"); 
...
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png");
```

Comment: Where do I put the @iconSpritePath? I'm using the whole pack. And should I move the images to the static/image folder? Right now, they are in the bootstrap/img folder.

Comment: @tipsywacky I updated my answer.. I guess you are using the css version so locate these lines in the bootstrap.css file and change them.

Answer (score 0):

Your css looks OK? this is what I am using that works

```
- url: /img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))
  static_files: static/img/\1
  upload: static/img/(.*\.(gif|png|jpg))

- url: /css
  static_dir: static/css

- url: /js
  mime_type: text/javascript
  static_dir: static/js
```

Then this should work etc

```
<i class="icon-search icon-white"></i>
```

Comment: You don't need to change the URL mapping, just to make the icons work. Read my answer for more..

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add one more step to make the answer from Lipis work for me.

Line 2285 in my bootstrap.css file originally read as follows, but the icons still didn't show up.

```
background-image: url("../img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

I then changed this relative path to an absolute path as follows, and the icons instantly appeared!

```
background-image: url("http://www.mywebsite.com/img/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

As to why the relative path did not resolve correctly, that's something for tomorrow.  In the meanwhile, at least the absolute path solution works for me (and perhaps for others).

Many thanks, Lipis, for your solution above.

Answer (score 0):

This topic is old, but maybe someone is looking for the answer to the similar problem. In my case it sufficed to add

```
- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts
```

in the app.yaml and leave bootstrap.css as it is. Glyphicons should naturally sit in the fonts folder in the root directory.